# How do I know when a new beta CD is released?

Tags: release-management

Recently I downloaded and installed the Ubuntu 10.10 beta CD. There was a problem with both my wired and wireless network adaptors during the installation which I'm hoping is resolved in a later beta release.

How can I determine when a later beta release is available?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [Maverick Release Schedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickReleaseSchedule) (via [Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) --> [MaverickMeerkat](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickMeerkat) --> [MaverickReleaseSchedule](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MaverickReleaseSchedule)).

The next CD released will be the Release Canditate, on September 30th.